# TagHandler to handle Youtube tag <iframe>?

Tags: android, html

I'm parsing html using Html.fromHtml(). My problem is that my html text has youtube embeded links (basically `<iframe>` tags)

So, since [Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class does NOT support `<iframe>` tag, I need to define my own [TagHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) to handle it. What I'm trying to do is to convert the `<iframe>` to a regular `<a>` tag so that it can be rendered correctly.

```
//convert this
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xAEdMI2ZE88" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
//To this
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xAEdMI2ZE88">Click to Watch</a>
```

My problem is that **I couldn't find a way to get the `src` link of the youtube from the `<iframe>` tag.**

Here is my TagHandler's `handleTag()` method:

```
@Override
public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
    if (tag.equals("iframe")) {
        if(opening) {
            output.append("<a href=");
            //How to get YouTube video link and append it?
        }
        else {
            output.append("Click To Watch</a>");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not change it in the string before you pass it to `Html.fromHtml()`?

Comment: I never thought of that. But wouldn't it be doable using `TagHandler`? Isn't it its job?

Comment: The problem is that `TagHandler`'s documentation is... limited, let's say. :-) I suspect the data you need is in the `XMLReader` parameter, but since they do not say what to expect there, it is a bit risky to rely upon it.

Comment: I will play around with `XMLReader`. I think I need to use your advice if I get stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, for now, took CommonsWare advice and modify the String `before` passing it to `Html.fromHtml`.

```
//Opening tag
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<iframe src");
Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlString);
while (m.find())
    htmlString= m.replaceAll("<a href");

//Closing tag    
p = Pattern.compile("frameborder=.*</iframe>");
m = p.matcher(htmlString);
while (m.find())
    htmlString= m.replaceAll(">CLICK TO WATCH</a>");
```

Comment: Untill somwone figure out a way to do it using `TagHandler`, this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: Not working in my case, it just showing normal string

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this regex.

```
htmlString.replaceAll("<iframe\\s+.*?\\s+src=(\".*?\").*?<\\/iframe>", "<a href=$1>CLICK TO WATCH</a>");
```