# Android video link display in android textview like we display images using html.imageGetter

Tags: android, html, video, iframe

Can we display a video from html content in TextView . Am displaying html content  in one of my Texview , am displaying images by implementing implements Html.ImageGetter , but does't have idea about displaying video,

My Html content is like this :

```
    <p>Police today baton charged hundreds of daily wagers working in                   various government departments during a protest here in which they were demanding regularisation of service.</p>
    <p>The workers assembled at Sher-e-Kashmir Park and started marching towards Lal Chowk area of the city raising slogans in favour of their demands, a police official said.</p>
    <p>He said as soon as the protesters crossed the Polo View crossing, police intercepted them and asked the protesters to disperse peacefully.</p>
   <p>However, they refused to pay any heed and tried to march ahead.</p>
   <p>The police used batons to disperse the protesters and took over 30 of them into preventive custody, the official said.</p>
   <p>No one was injured in the police action, he added.</p>
   <p><iframe width="480" height="315"   src="http video link url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">   </iframe></p>
```

at the end of the content i have video in iframe which i am not able to diplay, can we achieve this in android ?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we display a video from html content in TextView

No, sorry, `TextView` does not have the ability to display a video.

> can we achieve this in android ?

Use a `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I can't use WebView in this scenario.

Comment: @SajadBinNazir: Then you have no means of using that HTML verbatim. You are welcome to parse that HTML yourself and use something else for displaying the video (e.g., `VideoView`).

Answer (score 3):

You can also make a link from the iframe.

```
htmlString.replaceAll("<iframe\\s+.*?\\s+src=(\".*?\").*?<\\/iframe>", "<a href=$1>CLICK TO WATCH</a>");
```

Also postet here: 
[TagHandler to handle Youtube tag ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370792/594185)

Comment: This  looks cool idea in case we want to keep it as android content instead of using webview for just a video.